# If statement using php and advances custom fields in wordpress - hide empty fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an and if statement for a button.

If both advanced custom fields are present I want it to show the button and if not I want it to hide but I am struggling here.

I have looked at this page:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/hiding-empty-fields/

Here is my code:

```
<?php if( get_field('button_link') && get_field('button_text') ): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('button_link');  ?>" class="btn third-btn mx-auto">
    <?php the_field('button_text');?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Anyone got a suggestion please?

Cheers :)

Comment: I like to use get_post_meta() instead, seems much clearer to me but checkout the "value exists" option here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/  - your button_link and button_text fields may be returning an empty array or string, not a boolean false - so it evaluates your if block.

Comment: Both the link and text need to be populated in order for the statement to evaluate as true. Are you saying that your button renders even when those values are empty? I would debug that statement (xdebug, var_dump, or echo the results of `get_field('button_link')` and `get_field('button_text')` because they must contain a true-ish value (boolean true, non-empty string, or positive integer).

Comment: i see nothing wrong with ur code it's should display button when button_link and button_text field are not empty,use print_r(get_filed('button_link')); and print_r(get_filed('button_text')); to see if they have values

Comment: Thanks for all comments folks! Máximo sorted it for me :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an ACF expert but looking at the get_field() function description here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ it looks like the function will never return a boolean as mentioned on the Description and I quote:

> Returns the value of the specified field

Since it does not return a boolean value, you can't assure get_field( 'something' ) && get_field( 'something2' ) will be the correct boolean. There are certain values that the if statement interpret as boolean true or false. For example null and 0 are interpreted as false, but -1 interpreted as true. I would recommend to do a

```
var_dump( get_field('button_link') )
```

to explore the output. Also, according to https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ under 'Check if value exists' you can check if one value exists, so this might work:

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'button_link' ) ) : ?>
    <?php if ( get_field( 'button_text' ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_field( 'button_link' ) ?>" class="btn third-btn mx-auto">
            <?php the_field( 'button_text' ) ?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

It is like a nested AND without using the && operator. If this does not work we need more information about what you get from:

```
var_dump( get_field( 'button_link' ) );
var_dump( get_field( 'button_text' ) );
```

Comment: Máximo you have saved the day! Thanks for the answer, I just added that into my template and tested it out on the users point of view and works perfectly! I did think to nest it like this but didn't try it! Cheers for the help . - will mark this as answered :) Cheers!!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help. If you want to avoid multiple nested ANDs, you can program a mini function like: `function is_field_set( $field ) { return ( $field ) ? true : false; }` In that way you can safely do the `if ( is_field_set( get_field( 'one' ) ) && is_field_set( get_field( 'two' ) ) ) ... `